# WinForm WebBrowser control background color

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control in my Windows form application to display XML files. I am using web browser control so that I get the auto-formatting that web browser provides for my XML file, along with all other benefits of a web browser.

Now the problem is, the WebBrowser by default displays the background color in white when I open the XML file. I like to change it to another color, light blue. How to do this?

I tried some approaches like:

```
webBrowser.Document.Body.SetAttribute("bgcolor", "#738A9C");

webBrowser.DocumentText = "<html><body style='background-color:Blue'></body></html>";
```

But din't help. Any way to achieve this through CSS or XSLT or something?

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with xslt. This looks more like a setting in IE to display raw xml files.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to change the color settings in Internet Options->General tab->Colors. You can change the background color here, but it would be a global change, it'll set the background color of any website which doesn't specify it's own background color.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml-stylesheet type=“text/css" href="cd_catalog.css"?>
```

This should help you style everything using the `CSS` file. But then you lost the tree structure. 
Alternatively, check [this.](https://code.google.com/p/httpfox/source/browse/trunk/chrome/content/XMLPrettyPrint.xsl?r=3)
you can use something like that to still have a structure and add the background you want to that.
Then refer to the `xlst` from the `xml` document to style it accordingly.

Comment: [Also read this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754529(v=vs.85).aspx)